# Getting the content of a webpage (text) that use https WITHOUT curl on PHP

Tags: php, https

im using a very simple php script to retrive the text of a webpage;

```
$homepage = file_get_contents('http://192.168.1.125:6547/quickstatus');
echo $homepage;
```

But this instruction do not work on https, i dont have support for curl (im using a [php compiler](http://www.bambalam.se/bamcompile/)), is any way to retrive the content of a page that use https whitout curl???

Comment: The page you linked to seems to suggest cURL is supported.

Comment: but it doest work, dont know how to include the dll

Comment: U would suggest posting a question about getting that to work instead. Not that there aren't alternative solutions to cURL, but I think you'll find cURL to be the cleanest and you'd be happier getting that to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think if the function `file_get_contents` doesn't work with https address means that your installation of PHP has no `openssl` extension installed. That's why `curl` and other solutions will not be an option as well.

Answer (score 2):

`file_get_contents()` will work as long as PHP is compiled with [openssl](http://www.php.net/manual/book.openssl.php) support. If your installation does not include it, you can recompile (or reinstall a binary version of) PHP.

Please note this caveat from the [manual](http://www.php.net/manual/function.file-get-contents.php):

> When using SSL, Microsoft IIS will violate the protocol by closing the connection without sending a close_notify indicator. PHP will report this as "SSL: Fatal Protocol Error" when you reach the end of the data. To work around this, the value of error_reporting should be lowered to a level that does not include warnings. PHP 4.3.7 and higher can detect buggy IIS server software when you open the stream using the https:// wrapper and will suppress the warning. When using fsockopen() to create an ssl:// socket, the developer is responsible for detecting and suppressing this warning.

If you are attempting to connect to a server running IIS, this may also be a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [PEAR::HTTP_Request](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.http.http-request.intro.php).